# Creating a method that would allow button.Enable change unless all fields are NotEmptyOrNull Windows Application Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows app form C# with a submit button, on the `Form_Load` event,

```
SubBtnDisabled(BtnSubmit, TxtEduStat);
```

is called, which disabled the Submit button until all textboxes are filled... knowing that the `TxtEduStat` is the last text box field on the form, now logically speaking the user can start filling the textboxes in a reversed order, then the submit button will be enabled, and he (the user) will face Database error related to field can not be NULL.

So, I am trying to create a method that would not change the Submit button to `BtnSubmit.Enabled()` unless **ALL** TextBoxes hold values.

I am thinking to use the `List TextBox` approach, yet I am not sure if it will work! The image shows the initial look of the form:

[image: The image shows the initial look of the form]

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `TextChanged` event to re-validate entered values of all textboxes and enable or disable the button.

Comment: You mean call the method on every textbox or a similar method to the one i posted which is triggered on `TextChanged` ? @Sinatr

Comment: @AdamHaz Create only one event handler (one method) and subscribe to the `TextChanged` event of all (required) TextBoxes. For example, `textBox1.TextChanged += ValidateInputs; textBox2.TextChanged += ValidateInputs; // etc.`

Comment: Thank you @Sinatr :). 
I shall create it and update  you

Comment: Do you use Databinding? In that case check validity on the backing class the holds the data and not the textboxes.

Comment: @Ralf No mate I am not using that action, to be honest I am thinking about a totally different approach. hiding and showing text boxes